# Is Grails spring security plugin uses deprecated PasswordEncoder by default?

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

I'm using spring security plugin 2.0-RC2

Im trying to use the `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder` since `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder` is already deprecated.

But the BCryptPasswordEncoder being wired implements the deprecated one. I'm just wondering if the plugin still defaults in using the old implementations.

I peeked in the `SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy` I saw these lines:

```
/** passwordEncoder */
    if (conf.password.algorithm == 'bcrypt') {
        passwordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder, conf.password.bcrypt.logrounds) // 10
    }
    else if (conf.password.algorithm == 'pbkdf2') {
        passwordEncoder(PBKDF2PasswordEncoder)
    }
    else {
        passwordEncoder(MessageDigestPasswordEncoder, conf.password.algorithm) {
            encodeHashAsBase64 = conf.password.encodeHashAsBase64 // false
            iterations = conf.password.hash.iterations // 10000
        }
    }
```

All implementations of the deprecated interface. Do I have to create my own bean of the new encoders or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it does.Author of the plugin is working on using the latest one.

Comment: So, do we have use to deprecated one in the meantime?

Comment: Do you face any hurdle using the deprecated one?

Comment: Not really, I just think that there must be a good reason its deprecated.

Comment: @dmahapatro Do you know any links or article about the difference between the deprecated one and the new one? So I can justify using the deprecated one, if needed

Comment: API docs can be referred: [Deprecated PasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/PasswordEncoder.html) vs [PasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html).

Comment: I just found out that the plugin has an implementation of the deprecated passwordEncoder that has an encoder delegate that implements the new PasswordEncoder interface. So, I guess it is their way of using the new encoder. You have to use BCrypt though.